# Error in setDT(dat): while creating a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table

I am creating function for below activities:

```
library('data.table')
library(dplyr)
T2 <- dcast(test, Q27 ~ Q12_1_TEXT, fun.aggregate = length)
T3<-T2%>% mutate(Q27=as.character(Q27),"Todo el Mercado"=rowSums(T2[,2:ncol(T2)]))

ALL <- as.list( c( Q27 = "Número_de_Respuestas", colSums(T3[, 2:ncol(T3)]) ) )

T3[, 2:ncol(T3)]<- sapply(T3[, 2:ncol(T3)],prop.table)

T3[, 2:ncol(T3)]<- sapply(T3[, 2:ncol(T3)],function(x) paste0(round(x*100,0), "%"))
Tab <- rbindlist(l = list(T3, ALL)) 
Tab
```

Function looks like this:

```
Single_chile<-function(data,var1,var2){


Tab <- dcast(data, var1 ~ var2, fun.aggregate = length)

Tab1<-Tab%>% mutate(var1=as.character(var1),"Todo el Mercado"=rowSums(Tab[,2:ncol(Tab)]))

ALL <- as.list( c( var1 = "Número_de_Respuestas", colSums(Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)]) ) )

Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)]<- sapply(Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)],prop.table)

Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)]<- sapply(Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)],function(x) paste0(round(x*100,0), "%"))
Tab2 <- rbindlist(l = list(Tab1, ALL)) 

Tab2
}
```

Which when I run:

```
Single_chile(test,"Q27","Q12_1_TEXT")
```

gives below error:

> Error in setDT(dat) : All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length

where am I going wrong with this.

```
dput(test)
structure(list(Q27 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Si", "No"), class = "factor"), Q12_1_TEXT = c("Abertis Autopistas S.a.", 
"Accenture", "Adessa Falabella", "Administradora de Fondos de Cesantía", 
"AES GENER S.A.", "AFP HABITAT S.A.", "Agrícola Ariztía", "Agrosuper S.A.", 
"Aguas de Antofagasta S.A.", "AIG Chile Compañía de Seguros Generales S.A."
)), .Names = c("Q27", "Q12_1_TEXT"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get` function to fix your problem, like below. The problem is that you are using **var1** and **var2** parameter as strings, which is not getting translated correctly inside your function. You may use , `parse with eval` (NSE functions) to fix this or you can use `get`.

```
Single_chile<-function(data,var1,var2){


  Tab <- dcast(data, get(var1) ~ get(var2), fun.aggregate = length)

  Tab1<-Tab%>% mutate("Todo el Mercado"=rowSums(Tab[,2:ncol(Tab)]))

  ALL <- as.list( c( var1 = "Número_de_Respuestas", colSums(Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)]) ) )

  Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)]<- sapply(Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)],prop.table)

  Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)]<- sapply(Tab1[, 2:ncol(Tab1)],function(x) paste0(round(x*100,0), "%"))
  Tab2 <- rbindlist(l = list(Tab1, ALL)) 

  Tab2
}

Single_chile(test,"Q27","Q12_1_TEXT")
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use `debugonce(Single_chile)` and try running `Single_chile(test,"Q27","Q12_1_TEXT")` again to go inside the function and explore how it's working.

If you do so, you'll see the error comes from the first line:

```
dcast(data, var1 ~ var2, fun.aggregate = length)
```

The problem is `var1 ~ var2` is a formula, and you've supplied `var1` and `var2` as strings (i.e., what the function sees is `'Q27' ~ 'Q12_1_TEXT'`, **not** `Q27 ~ Q12_1_TEXT` as you intended). What you *really* want (in your test case) is

```
dcast(data, Q27 ~ Q12_1_TEXT, fun.aggregate = length)
```

There are a few ways to do this. Closest to your approach would be to build the formula from a string:

```
f = as.formula(sprintf('%s ~ %s', var1, var2))
dcast(data, f, fun.aggregate = length)
```

There are some more issues with your function, but I'll leave it to you to explore what's going wrong.